# Couldn't get jquery datepicker onshow function triggered

Tags: jquery, datepicker

***Using:*** jquery-1.4.4, jquery-ui-1.7.2

***Problem:***
go through several sections, every section has **dateFrom** and **dateTo**.
I need to prepopulate **minDate** of **dateTo** with currently selected date of **dateFrom**
the right place is **dateTo.onShow**

***Symptoms:*** 
setting the break point inside onShow function, clicking datepicker dateTo, not stopped at bp.

***here is the code:***

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name^="section"]').each(function(i){
  var sectionId = $(this).attr('sectionId');
  var date2 = "#date2";
  date2 = date2.concat(sectionId);
  if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
     $(date2).datepicker().datepicker('enable');
  } else {
     $(date2).datepicker().datepicker('disable');
  }
  $(date2).datepicker({
    onShow: function(picker, inst) {
      var sectionId = $(picker).attr('sectionId');
      var date1 = "#date1";
      date1 = date1.concat(sectionId);
      var dateMin = $(date1).val();
      picker.datepicker('minDate', dateMin);
    }
 });
});
});
```

Thanks,
VB

Answer:
Here is simple fix:

```
$(function() {
 $('input[name^="section"]').each(function(i){
   var sectionId = $(this).attr('sectionId');
   var date2 = "#date2";
   date2 = date2.concat(posterId);
   $(date2).datepicker('option', {
      beforeShow: processUnpostMinDate
   });
 });
});
function processUnpostMinDate(picker) {
  var posterId = $(picker).attr('sectionId');
  var date1 = "#date1";
  date1 = date1.concat(sectionId);
  return {
     minDate: $(date1).datepicker("getDate") 
  };
}
```

Regards,

VB

Comment: You should post your as a new answer to the question, and accept it. No one looks for the answer in the question. Or at least accept the James Montagne's answer ticking it as such, which addressed the pitfall of your problem.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you want `beforeShow`.  I don't see an `onShow` in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both. Doesn't work. Not onShow, nether beforeShow